# Make the selected option uppercase in a dropdown using vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, css

I need to make the text uppercase on the *selected option only* in a `<select>`. I found a [working example using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26323135/how-to-display-selected-value-of-a-dropdown-alone-in-uppercase) but I need to convert it to **vanilla JS**.

I've actually got it pretty close, when you choose an option, it makes the selected value uppercase. But when you choose another, it leaves the previous option uppercase also.

I can't figure out how to say "Capitalise all options EXCEPT the selected option, which I would like to be uppercase".

Any guidance will be appreciated.

[**Here is a working Fiddle of where I am so far**](https://jsfiddle.net/xcbvekae/9/).

Comment: Add the code here too.

Answer (score 3):

How about just using CSS

```css
* {
  font-family: arial;
}

select option {
  text-transform: capitalize;
}

select, select option:checked {
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<select name="title" id="title">
    <option selected="" disabled="">Categories</option>
    <option value="photo-galleries">Photo Galleries</option>
    <option value="photography">photography</option>
    <option value="romeo-juliet">Romeo &amp; Juliet</option>
    <option value="swan-lake">Swan Lake</option>
    <option value="symmetries">Symmetries</option>
</select>

<select name="day" id="day">
    <option selected="" disabled="">Day of the week</option>
    <option value="monday">Monday</option>
    <option value="tuesday">Tuesday</option>
    <option value="wednesday">Wednesday</option>
    <option value="thursday">Thursday</option>
    <option value="friday">Friday</option>
    <option value="saturday">Saturday</option>
    <option value="sunday">Sunday</option>
</select>
```

---

Here's a javascript version as well

```
[].slice.call( document.querySelectorAll('option') ).forEach(ucfirst);

document.getElementById('title').addEventListener('change', fn, false);
document.getElementById('day').addEventListener('change', fn, false);

function ucfirst(el) {
    el.innerHTML = el.innerHTML.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + el.innerHTML.slice(1).toLowerCase();
}

function fn() {
    var options  = this.getElementsByTagName('option');
    var selected = options[this.selectedIndex];

    [].slice.call(options).forEach(ucfirst);
    selected.value = selected.innerHTML = selected.innerHTML.toUpperCase();
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/2be1w4xg/)

Comment: This is great! But unfortunately I need it to work in Webkit browsers (Chrome, Safari). I notice that this doesn't work. I assume this is a bug in those browsers. Is there a workaround or do I still need to explore a JavaScript solution?

Comment: I notice that it's working on Chrome on Windows (Chrome 48, Windows 10) but not OSX (Chrome 48, Yosemite or El Capitan). I guess this must be a bug in OSX.

Comment: @MikeeBee - there's no reason it shouldn't work the same in Chrome on OSX as it does in Windows? I added a javascript version as well.

Comment: I know, I'm pretty puzzled why it's not working! Shame to have to resort to JS for something like this.

Thanks so much for providing a JS version! Is it supposed to be making the first/initial option uppercase? It doesn't seem to be (Chrome, FF on OSX). Also, what would be the best approach to fire this for each select on a page?